# The thread stack is not fully executed and switches to mine

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin

There is a function that receives data from the Firebase database and creates a list from this. I need to do this in a separate thread. I tried to do this, but it looks like some of the code is being executed in a side thread and some in mine.

Fun:

```
fun initUserTracks() {
    userTracks = mutableListOf()
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_TRACKS).child(UID)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(AppValueEventListener {
            thread {
                it.children.forEach { trackID ->
                    Log.d("dbThread", Thread.currentThread().name)
                    var userTrack = UserTrack(TYPE_CONTENT)
                    userTrack.distance =
                        trackID.child(CHILD_DISTANCE).getValue(Double::class.java)!!

                    userTrack.time = LocationConverter.convertMStoTime(
                        trackID.child(CHILD_TIME).getValue(Long::class.java)!!
                    )
                    userTrack.startTime =
                        timeToDate(
                            trackID.child(CHILD_START_TIME).getValue(Long::class.java)!!
                        )

                    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_TRACKS).child(UID)
                        .child(trackID.key.toString()).child(
                            CHILD_TRACK_POINTS
                        ).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(AppValueEventListener { tracks ->

                            tracks.children.forEach { points ->
                        Log.d("dbThread", Thread.currentThread().name)
                                var pointsList = mutableListOf<Point>()

                                points.children.forEach { point ->
                                    pointsList.add(
                                        Point(

                                            point.child(CHILD_LATITUDE)
                                                .getValue(Double::class.java) as Double,
                                            point.child(CHILD_LONGITUDE)
                                                .getValue(Double::class.java) as Double
                                        )
                                    )

                                }

                                userTrack.trackPoints = pointsList

                            }

                            userTracks.add(userTrack)
                        }
                        )

                }
            }

        })


}
```

If you look at the logs, it turns out like this:

```
2020-10-17 16:07:31.015 29067-29165/com.example.gotracker D/dbThread: Thread-19
2020-10-17 16:07:31.048 29067-29165/com.example.gotracker D/dbThread: Thread-19
2020-10-17 16:07:31.177 29067-29067/com.example.gotracker D/dbThread: main
2020-10-17 16:07:31.304 29067-29067/com.example.gotracker D/dbThread: main
```

but I need everything that is inside thread {} to be executed in a side thread. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Instead of creating your own threads, use dedicated thread pools for thread management.  If you want to execute something on a signle thread in background use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor() and use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#supplyAsync-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.concurrent.Executor- to execute your work on separate threadpool

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this in one thread:

```
fun initUserTracks() {
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    var userTrack = UserTrack(TYPE_CONTENT)
    userTracks = mutableListOf()
    REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_TRACKS).child(UID)
        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(AppValueEventListener {


            it.children.forEach { trackID ->


                executor.execute {
                    userTrack = UserTrack(TYPE_CONTENT)
                    Log.d("dbThread", Thread.currentThread().name)

                    userTrack.distance =
                        trackID.child(CHILD_DISTANCE).getValue(Double::class.java)!!

                    userTrack.time = LocationConverter.convertMStoTime(
                        trackID.child(CHILD_TIME).getValue(Long::class.java)!!
                    )
                    userTrack.startTime =
                        timeToDate(
                            trackID.child(CHILD_START_TIME).getValue(Long::class.java)!!
                        )


                }



                REF_DATABASE_ROOT.child(NODE_TRACKS).child(UID)
                    .child(trackID.key.toString()).child(
                        CHILD_TRACK_POINTS
                    ).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(AppValueEventListener { tracks ->

                        tracks.children.forEach { points ->
                            executor.execute {
                                Log.d("dbThread", Thread.currentThread().name)
                                var pointsList = mutableListOf<Point>()

                                 points.children.forEach { point ->
                                    pointsList.add(
                                        Point(

                                            point.child(CHILD_LATITUDE)
                                                .getValue(Double::class.java) as Double,
                                            point.child(CHILD_LONGITUDE)
                                                .getValue(Double::class.java) as Double
                                        )
                                    )
                                }


                                userTrack.trackPoints =  pointsList
                            }
                        }

                        userTracks.add(userTrack)
                    }
                    )


            }


        })
  

}
```

Log:

*2020-10-24 12:39:41.719 15347-15455/com.example.gotracker D/dbThread: pool-4-thread-1

2020-10-24 12:39:42.025 15347-15455/com.example.gotracker D/dbThread: pool-4-thread-1*